# How to visualize the .cfg dump of gcc

Tags: gcc, visualization, control-flow

I have got the control-flow graph of a .c file using -fdump-tree-cfg option of gcc. But, I do not know how to see this .cfg file. Is there anyway to convert this to a .dot or is there any tool that can directly visualize the .cfg files?

Comment: it seems that you already figured out how to visualize it based on your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25330935/6220384). Do you mind if you add it to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to attempt [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-11/msg00395.html) suggestion on the gcc-help archive ? Its a similar requirement someone posted on gcc-help mailing list.

Comment: Tried that. Does not work. Already found another way to get the gimple-based control flow using gcc-python-plugin.